# Thinktecture.IdentityModel with SimpleMembership

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, authentication, thinktecture-ident-model

I want to use ASP.NET SimpleMembership to authenticate users that consume my WebAPI.  Thinktecture has a wonderful authentication library called Thinktecture.IdentityModel (http://thinktecture.github.com/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.45/) with an example that ties Forms Auth with Basic Auth ([source](http://leastprivilege.com/2012/10/23/mixing-mvc-forms-authentication-and-web-api-basic-authentication/)).  However, the example uses Membership.ValidateUser() which doesn't work without a ASP.NET Membership provider, which isn't supported by SimpleMembership ([source](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx)) (**edit**: this isn't entirely true, see Mark's answer below).

---

**Edit**:

Here's what I did:

1) Create a new MVC Internet Application

2) Install Thinktecture.IdentityModel via NuGet

3) Create a model and an api controller via scaffolding:

```
public class Goober
{
    public int GooberId { get; set; }
    public string GooberWords { get; set; }
}
```

4) Ran the project, created a new user and created a new Goober using Fiddler

5) Added [Authorize] to GetGoober(int id)

6) In WebApiConfig.cs added:

```
var authConfig = new AuthenticationConfiguration();

authConfig.AddBasicAuthentication((userName, password) =>
    Membership.ValidateUser(userName, password));

config.MessageHandlers.Add(new AuthenticationHandler(authConfig));
```

When I run the project and hit api/goober/1 with Fiddler I get a **401 www-Authenticate: unspecified**.  But if I log in first using the AccountController then use Fiddler I get a **200** and everything is peachy.

**Edit**

Okay, I think the problem isn't related to my initial question.  I suspect it's related to the initialization of SimpleMembership in the template.  When I open the project and run debug then hit the api with Fiddler I can't get past Auth.  But when I simply click the "register" link on the web frontend I get past Auth.  I'm guessing it's because the InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute is called at the AccountController so doesn't initialize until the controller is called?

---

I've tried using WebSecurity.Login() in the place of Membership.ValidateUser() but that doesn't work.

I'm at a loss on how to actually implement this.  Does anyone have any advice? Or maybe I'm attempting to tackle this problem from the wrong angle?

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that ASP.NET Membership provider is not compatible with the `SimpleMembershipProvider` however `SimpleMembershipProvider` does support `ValidateUser`, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider.validateuser%28v=vs.111%29.aspx). Assuming SimpleMembership is correctly configured and initalised you should still be able to call `Membership.ValidateUser()`.

If you have already tried `Membership.ValidateUser()` and got an error please let me know and we can try resolve it.

**Update**

So having followed your reproduction steps I have managed to pin-point an error. Having brought the Thinktecture `AuthenticationHandler` handler inline and run in debug. 30 seconds after a request to the api controller a database connection error is being raised. This is failing asynchronously and silently.

After some fiddling around I believe it is the `DefaultConnection` connection string which is at fault.

Like me your default connection probably contains a file name like this: 
    AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcApplication3-20121215104323.mdf"

When ValidateUser is called inside the delegate registered at app start up (for validating the credentials) it appears to be failing to resolve `|DataDirectory|` I found that by updating this path to the full name my connection problems went away.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcApplication3-20121215104323;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=C:\mydatabase\file\path\example\aspnet-MvcApplication-20121215104323.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I then found this post [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/dc31ea59-5718-49b6-9f1f-7039da425296/), it indicates that the AppDomain has not had it's data directory set correctly at this point.

So once the config set up and the connection string altered with a proper file path and a user name "test" and a password "testing" this request through fiddler got a 200:

```
GET http://localhost/api/goober/1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost
Authorization: Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0aW5n
```

***As an aside***

I found that to get the forms authorisation token to also allow access to the api controllers I had to add this. Otherwise the Thinkteckture code sets the principle back to anonymous:

Add this

```
authConfig.InheritHostClientIdentity = true;
```

To counteract [this](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.45/blob/master/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/Tokens/Http/AuthenticationHandler.cs) (line 52):

```
if (_authN.Configuration.InheritHostClientIdentity == false)
{
   //Tracing.Information(Area.HttpAuthentication, "Setting anonymous principal");
   SetPrincipal(Principal.Anonymous);
}
```

Comment: Hi Mark -- thanks for the reply!  I did try Membership.ValidateUser() but couldn't get it to work.  I will update my question tomorrow when I get back to the office.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: @brudert great stuff, let me know what the error was for ValidateUser() and we can get that fixed.

Comment: @brudert hi I have updated my answer. Sample code on Github. be sure to set your proper path in the connection strings. https://github.com/markyjones/StackOverflow/tree/master/SimpleMembershipWithWebApiAndHttpBasicAuth

Comment: Wow, great update!  Unfortunately, it didn't work for me :(  After re-reading our correspondence I decided to try to call InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute() directly from FilterConfig.cs [filters.Add(new InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute());] to make sure the simplemembership database was set up correctly before I did an API call.  Sure enough, it worked!

Comment: Perhaps we are finding different solutions to the same problem?  If your database was set up prior to you using its full path maybe the problem just disappeared and your solution is a coincidence? We can test this by dropping the db and rerunning the app.  If I find time in the next day or so I'll download your project from github (thanks for that, by the way!) and test it.

Comment: @brudert the database was indeed already there as I needed it to create a user to attempt to login as(!). I think the DataDirectory issue I was having may be environmental, perhaps specific to me (Win 8). I will leave it in the answer for anyone else you has that issue.